# Programmatically load layout into another layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-xml, android-recyclerview

I have a layout, `images.xml`, that I want to load/inflate into another layout, `main.xml`.

Here is the main layout, `main.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

    // Load into placeholder
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/placeholder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/desc"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

And here is `images.xml`, the layout I want to load into the above layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

I use a RecyclerView adapter that I use to load data into the main layout and this is where I want to load/inflate the sub-layout:

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private static Context context;
    private List<Message> mDataset;

    public RecyclerAdapter(Context context, List<Message> myDataset) {
        this.context = context;
        this.mDataset = myDataset;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnCreateContextMenuListener, View.OnClickListener {
        public TextView title;
        public LinearLayout placeholder;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            view.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(this);

            title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
            placeholder = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.placeholder);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.message_layout, parent, false);
        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder((LinearLayout) view);

        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Message item = mDataset.get(position);

        holder.title.setText(item.getTitle());

        int numImages = item.getImages().size();

        if (numImages > 0) {
            View test = LayoutInflater.from(holder.placeholder.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.images, holder.placeholder, false);
            ImageView image = (ImageView) test.findViewById(R.id.image);
            Glide.with(context)
                .load("http://www.website.com/test.png")
                .fitCenter()
                .into(image);
            holder.placeholder.addView(test);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDataset.size();
    }

}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 5):

> I have a layout, images.xml, that I want to load/inflate into another
>   layout, main.xml

Do it as:

**1.** First add `orientation` for `LinearLayout` in `main.xml` as `vertical` :

```
android:orientation="vertical"
```

**2.** Use `holder.title` or  `holder` in `onBindViewHolder` to get parent layout in which want to add  `images.xml` :

```
  LinearLayout linearLayout=(LinearLayout)holder.title.getParent();
  View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
                                             R.layout.images, parent, false);
    linearLayout.addView(view);
```

Comment: The `(ViewGroup)` cast is redundant.

Comment: If I, for example, added a `LinearLayout` in `main.xml` where I want the layout to be loaded, can I use your method to load the layout into the `LinearLayout`?

Comment: @MikeM. because Layout contain LinearLayout as root Container but `getParent` return `ViewGroup` so im casting it to LinearLayout. which is useful when we want to access view from inflated layout using findViewById

Comment: @user5578746: yes layout loaded as sub-view of LinearLayout probably after then TextView. and if getting any issue then Use RelativeLayout instead of LinerLayout for positioning added layout using according to need

Comment: How efficient is this, performance wise, in a RecyclerView adapter?

Comment: @user5578746: i think no issue with performance because View also recycled in RecyclerView

Comment: One problem I have. It works, but some of the recyclerview items are showing images when they shouldn't have any images. How can I fix this?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK Actually, `View#getParent()` returns a `ViewParent` object. And `LinearLayout` is a `ViewGroup`, so I don't understand what you're saying about `findViewById()`.

Comment: @user5578746: then add condition before adding image layout if image is not available then no need to add image layout if image available then add it

Comment: I added this to the adapter, but it's still showing images for some items when it shouldn't be: http://pastebin.com/nM1eSSb0

Comment: @MikeM.: as in my answer i also mention :`Use holder.title or  holder` so we can use both(casting to LinearLayout or using ViewGroup). thanks for pointing this point. but suppose we want to set `Orientation` of image.xml LinearLayout using code then using `ViewGroup` not possible we need to cast it to LinearLayout. i hope you understand what i want to say.

Comment: @user5578746: dude. `numImages > 0` condition i think always `true` because `items.getImages()` returning more then 0 size

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK I think I understand you. But then why can't you just cast directly to `LinearLayout`?

Comment: I just tried printing it. It returns `SIZE: 0` for many of the items, but still shows the images.

Comment: @MikeM.: Yes thanks so much you are right. updated my answer

Answer (score 3):

**1. If you want to do it programmatically
use ViewStub**

```
<ViewStub
    android:id="@+id/layout_stub"
    android:inflatedId="@+id/message_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.75" />
```

then in your java class do this

```
ViewStub stub = (ViewStub) findViewById(R.id.layout_stub);
stub.setLayoutResource(R.layout.whatever_layout_you_want);
View inflated = stub.inflate();
```

2. **Use [include](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html)**

your main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />

// Load sub-layout here

<include
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:id="@+id/some_id_if_needed"
   layout="@layout/images"/>
```

your sub layout

images.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
```

Comment: Would ViewStub work in a RecyclerView though? Since the ViewStub is replaced by the layout, wouldn't it crash the app since it wouldn't be able to find the ViewStub if I scrolled?

Comment: @user5578746 I personally never tried with recyclerView, but I am sure it can be done via your adapter, using getItemViewType() method.

Comment: see this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31609215/is-there-a-way-to-use-a-viewstub-inside-a-recyclerview

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

    // Load sub-layout here
<include layout = "@layout/images"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

You should use `include` tag to include another layout into main layout

**Edit**

To programatically add view try this

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
 View inflatedLayout= inflater.inflate(R.layout.images, null, false);
 mainView.addView(inflatedLayout);
```

Comment: I need to do it programmatically, within the RecyclerView adapter.

Comment: @user5578746 try this LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
 View inflatedLayout= inflater.inflate(R.layout.yourLayout, null, false);
 containerDestacado.addView(inflatedLayout);

Answer (score 0):

Change your main.xml to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

    // Load sub-layout here
<include
        android:id="@+id/imageLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        layout="@layout/images" />
</LinearLayout>
```

to include one layout view into another `<include layout="@layout/your_layout"/>` is the tag used in xml file to achieve this.

To add the view dynamically below code will help:

change your main.xml to following code:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/ll_mainLayout"     
        android:layout_width="match_parent"  
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />

        // Load sub-layout here

    </LinearLayout>
```

Write following code to add view dynamically:

```
// get your outer relative layout 
LinearLayout ll_mainLayout= (LinearLayout) findById(R.id.ll_mainLayout);


// inflate content layout and add it to the relative layout as second child 
// add as second child, therefore pass index 1 (0,1,...) 

LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) 
        this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);    
rl.addView(1, layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.images, this, false) );
```

Comment: I need to do it programmatically, within the RecyclerView adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Include the second layout inside the main layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/title"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     />

   <include layout="@layout/images.xml" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I need to do it programmatically, within the RecyclerView adapter.

Answer (score -2):

To include another layout into your current layout file:

```
  <include layout="@layout/titlebar"/>
```

where titlebar.xml is another layout file. For more please visit: http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html